# Riemann sum to integration

Tags: calculus, integration

Assume that $f(x)$ is continuous over $[a, b]$, and define $\Delta x=\frac{b-a}{n}$.
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\left(a+(k+1)\Delta x\right)
-f(a+k\Delta x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{f\left(a+k\Delta x+\Delta x\right)
-f(a+k\Delta x)}{\Delta x}\Delta x\\
\begin{align}
f(b)-f(a)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{f\left(a+k\Delta x+\Delta x\right)
-f(a+k\Delta x)}{\Delta x}\Delta x\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f'(a+k\Delta x)\Delta x\\
&=\int_a^bf'(x)dx
\end{align}
$$
Why are we allowed to not make $k\Delta x$ zero from line three to line four? It feels like we haven't "really" computed the limit. We have just applied it to the function by transforming it into its derivative, but we have left everything else intact.

Comment: What do you mean by making $k\Delta$ zero? $k$ is an integer taking values $0$ to $n-1$ and $\Delta$ is half of the symbol $\Delta x$ which is defined above.

Comment: that is a typo. thanks.

Comment: I think part of what you're asking might be what is stopping us from applying the limit to the expression $k\Delta x$ and getting $0$? In order to apply the limit to the expression $k\Delta x$, the limit would need to be brought inside the sum, but the upper summation limit depends on $n$, so this cannot be done. Also, even if that were somehow possible, for example, consider $k=n-1$. Then $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(n-1)(b-a)}{n} = (b-a)$, not $0$.

Comment: @Luyw, in addition to Adina Goldberg's comment, how do you know, if you were able to bring the limit inside the sum, that the limit $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{f\left(a+k\Delta x+\Delta x\right)-f(a+k\Delta x)}{\Delta x}\Delta x.$$ does exist for all $k$?